# Orthogonal decomposition of a Matrix with constraints

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ with $d>n$.
Also, $\mathbf{B}$ can be a tight frame in some case.

Can someone suggest a method to decompose $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{B=CD}$ for orthogonal $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $

Comment: QR? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @cooper.hat See D is fixed, arbitrary and not triangular

Comment: If $B$ has $n$ linearly independent columns then you have no choice in the matter.

Comment: @cooper.hat Let $\mathbf{B}$ is a equal norm tight frame, can we have some other efficient structures for $\mathbf{C}$ e.g. toeplitz or circulant